# Access a hard drive USB-connected to a router: Failed to Mount Windows Share

Tags: samba, router

I've connected a hard drive to a router - via USB cable - to enable LAN file sharing. So far it is possible to access from an android device. The device is also detected on Ubuntu, but it's not possible to access it. By double clicking the folder it prints:

```
Failed to Mount Windows Share: Software caused connection to abort
```

The filesystem of the drive is NTFS.

The router config indicates the file share is a samba share, so this should be fine too. And as said, it's possible to read books etc from android phone.

Any idea?

**Router**: [EE BrightBox](https://shop.ee.co.uk/broadband/ee-bright-box-router)

Comment: Could you update your question to include the brand and model of the router? This might help someone provide specific solutions 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Failed to Mount Windows Share: Software caused connection to abort

You will get that error if the only dialect of smb the server can use is SMB1. By default a modern Linux samba client disables SMB1.

You have two choices:

[1] Force the Linux client to use SMB1 ( Samba calls SMB1 NT1 ):

Edit /etc/samba/smb.conf and right under the `workgroup = WORKGROUP` line add this one: `client min protocol = NT1`

If you didn't install the samba package because you have no need to be a Samba server install the smbclient package which will provide an smb.conf file to edit:

```
sudo apt install smbclient
```

[2] OR you can do a cifs mount which I can explain if you want to go down that path.

Comment: I am a samba server too, would [2] be problematic?

Comment: Nope. It just means you already have a smb.conf to edit. After editing run the following command to keep everyone happy: `sudo service smbd restart`

Comment: Option 1 worked perfectly. Thank you so much, it was a bit frustrating. Did you google it or how did you find out?

Comment: Samba is pretty much the only thing I write about. I'm one of those poor saps that reads the changelogs on every single %$&@ samba point release.

Comment: Modern Windows as well has SMB1 disabled by default. The problem would be the same.