# Connecting to password protected samba on Dolphin errors, `Connection to host 192.168.11.1 is broken.`

Tags: networking, kubuntu, password, samba, dolphin

I am trying to connect to a samba. Apparently I was given a username and password, and that according to tutorials, that if I merely place this in, I should be prompted with a username and password prompt. None comes up, and only this appears:
[image]
If I try to put the username and password in manually, the same error applies.

How can I connect to this samba share with Dolphin? What is the error telling me?
Thanks.

Comment: Not a KDE user but I have a hunch it is the KDE equivalent of this one with the same fix: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335495/access-a-hard-drive-usb-connected-to-a-router-failed-to-mount-windows-share   Easy enough to undo if my hunch is wrong.

Comment: @Morbius1 That more or less solved it. I ended up using this command, `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=foo,pass=bar,vers=1.0 //192.168.11.1/marketing1    /home/anon/Documents/NLBC/Marketing` and then the shares were accessible in Dolphin.